# copy constructor for class with pointers as member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

i'm trying to write  a copy constructor program for char pointer and int pointer ..
i'm trying to copy content of object a1 to a2 and trying to display the values of a2..
the value of integer pointer is displayed correctly,but it is not printing the value pointed by char pointer,Please let me know what is the problem with this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
class a
{
    private:
    char *sptr;
    int *i = new int;
    public:
    a()
    {

    }
    a(char str[])
    {

        sptr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy( sptr, str );
        *i=5;
    }
    a(const a& source)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        sptr = new char[strlen(source.sptr) + 1];
        strcpy( sptr, source.sptr);
        i = source.i; 
    }

    ~a()
    {
        cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
         delete sptr;
    }

    a operator=( const a& other )
    {
        cout<<"assigment overload"<<endl;
        if(&other!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"inside assignment";
            a tmp( other );   //  Copy first, then swap.
            //std::swap( i, tmp.i );
            // std::swap( sptr, tmp.sptr );
            // strcpy( sptr, tmp.sptr);
        }
        return *this;     //  Dtor of tmp will clean up.
    }

void display()
    {

        // while(*sptr!='\0')
        // {
        //     cout<< *sptr;
        //     sptr++;
        // }
        // cout<<endl;
        // cout<<"i="<<*i<<endl;

        for ( char const* p = sptr; *p != '\0'; ++ p ) {
            cout << *p;
        }

    }
};
int main()
{
   // cout<<"contents of a1"<<endl;
   a a1("123456789898900");
   // a1.display();
   // a a2(a1);   
   // cout<<"contents of a2"<<endl;
   // a2.display();
   a a3;
   a3 = a1;
   // a3.display();
   return 0;
}
```

my modified program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
class a
{
    private:
    char *sptr;
    // int *i = new int;
    public:
    a()
    {

    }
    a(char str[])
    {

        sptr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy( sptr, str );
        // *i=5;
    }
    a(const a& source)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        sptr = new char[strlen(source.sptr) + 1];
        strcpy( sptr, source.sptr);
        // i = source.i; 
    }

    ~a()
    {

         delete sptr;
         cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
    }

    a operator=( const a& other )
    {
        cout<<"assigment overload"<<endl;
        if(&other!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"inside assignment";
            a tmp( other );   //  Copy constructor is called
            sptr = new char[strlen(tmp.sptr) + 1];
            strcpy( sptr, tmp.sptr);
        }//destructor is called once for tmp variable when it goes out of scope
        return *this;     //   Copy constructor is called,pass by value
    }//destructor is called once for this variable when it goes out of scope

void display()
    {

        // while(*sptr!='\0')
        // {
        //     cout<< *sptr;
        //     sptr++;
        // }
        // cout<<endl;
        // cout<<"i="<<*i<<endl;

        for ( char const* p = sptr; *p != '\0'; ++ p ) {
            cout << *p;
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }
};
int main()
{
   cout<<"contents of a1"<<endl;
   a a1("123456789898900");
   a1.display();
   a a2(a1);   //copy constructor called
   cout<<"contents of a2"<<endl;
   a2.display();
   a a3;
   a3 = a1;
   cout<<"contents of a3"<<endl;
   a3.display();
   return 0;
}//destructor called for a1,a2,a3


output:
contents of a1
123456789898900
copy constructor
contents of a2
123456789898900
assigment overload
inside assignmentcopy constructor
destructor called
copy constructor
destructor called
contents of a3
123456789898900
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```

Comment: You are allocating dynamic memory (both the C way for `sptr` and the C++ way for `i`), and the question is *why* ? For `i`, it is unnecessary as far as I can see, for `sptr`, you would be better off using `std::string`.

Comment: i'm trying to write a program that can add big integer values 
for example like this
11111111111111111111111111111 + 111111111111111111111111 =222222222222222222222222222

so i'm trying to get the input in character array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking `a1.display()`, `sptr` gets increment to the end of the string.

In the copy constructor, `sptr` is copied to `a2`, it still points to the end of the string.

I would suggest using a local char pointer in your display function. This would fix the problem.

Comment: Yep, there are. Just trying to help one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's not at all clear what the semantics should
be (nor why you're using `int*`).  Do you want a deep copy
(which is probably the only thing which makes sense given your
first constructor); in that case, you need to implement the deep
copy in the copy constructor; you also need to add an assignment
operator and a destructor.  (Without a destructor, you leak
memory.)  As for the concrete errors in what you do have:

```
sptr = (char*)malloc( sizeof( strlen( str ) ) );
```

- `strlen` returns a `size_t`, so `sizeof( strlen( str ) )` is the
  same as `sizeof( size_t )`: probably either 4 or 8.  You
  probably want just `strlen( str ) + 1`.  (`+ 1` because `strlen`
  doesn't count the final `'\0'`.)
- If this is C++, you would be much better off using `new char[strlen(str) + 1]`, and avoiding the cast.

  sptr = str;
- You've now overwritten the pointer you got back from `malloc`,
  so you will inevitably leak memory.  Also, the validity of
  `sptr` now depends on the lifetime of the argument; if it's
  a string literal, fine, but otherwise, you're likely to end up
  with a dangling pointer.  What you probably wanted was
  `strcpy( sptr, ptr );`, to copy the actual characters.

And of course, I repeat the question: why is `i` a pointer, and
not just an `int`?

In your copy constructor, you don't do a deep copy; if this is
intentional, either you shouldn't be allocating memory in the
other constructor, or you need some sort of reference counting.
What you probably want is something more along the lines of:

```
A::A( A const& other )
    : i( other.i )      //  Assuming that `i` is `int`, and not `int*`
    : sptr( new char[strlen( other.sptr ) + 1] )
{
    strcpy( sptr, other.sptr );
}
```

And of course, you need an assignment operator and a destructor:

```
A& A::operator=( A const& other )
{
    A tmp( other ):   //  Copy first, then swap.
    std::swap( i, tmp.i );
    std::swap( sptr, tmp.sptr );
    return *this;     //  Dtor of tmp will clean up.
}

A::~A()
{
    delete sptr;
}
```

If `i` is really a pointer, you'll have to treat it similarly in
the constructors and destructor.

Finally, in your `display` function, you're modifying the member
pointer in the loop, which means that the next time around,
you'll find it pointing to the `'\0'`.  The output should be:

```
for ( char const* p = sptr; *sptr != '\0'; ++ p ) {
    std::cout << *p;
}
```

(I'm supposing here that you are doing this for pedantic
reasons.  If `sptr` points to a `'\0'` string, then
`std::cout << sptr << std::endl;` is all you need in `display`.)

Comment: Thank you...i have modified the code accordingdly but i'm getting an error in A& A::operator=( A const& other ) function

i have modified the original code pasted above..
error:
main.cpp: In member function ‘a& a::operator=(const a&)’: main.cpp:35:21: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand 
return &this; // Dtor of tmp will clean up. ^

Comment: @Priya Yes.  There's a rather obvious typo: the return value should be `*this`, not `&this`.